# Why the jQuery colorbox popup is not getting displayed when called through $.ajax() method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, colorbox

I'm calling a hidden colorbox popup in the $.ajax() method's success: function() but I'm not able to show that. I did the same thing previously but at that time it worked fine, now it's not displaying the specified hidden pop-up. The only difference from this implementation to previous implementation I was using data attrribute of $.ajax() method in the previous implementation. Does that thing is responsible for my current issue? Please help me out in resolving this issue. For your reference I'm putting the necessary code snippets as follows:

```
    <div class="hidden">
      <div id="emailinfoPopContent" class="c-popup">
        <h2 class="c-popup-header">Email Invoice</h2>
        <div class="c-content">         
          <h3>Invoice has been sent to your email id</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on('click', '#email_url', function (e) { 

    e.preventDefault();

    var post_url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: post_url,
      type : 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
      var status       = data.status;
      var dialog_title = "Email Invoice";
      var message      = data.msg; 

      if(status == 'success') {
        $.colorbox({
          inline:true, 
          href: "#emailinfoPopContent",
          width:666
        });
        //alert(message);          
      } else {     
        $.colorbox({
          inline:true, 
          href: "#emailinfoPopContent",
          width:666
          });    
        //alert(message);           
        }  
      }
    });  
  });
});

</script>
```

One more thing I wold like to say is I'm getting the proper response from PHP code in json format, if I show alert instead of colorbox it shows the desired response properly. There are no syntactical errors found in firebug console and I'm using jQuery 1.9

Comment: In above code where you calling dialogue box ?

Comment: @Shafeeq:Sorry, Iplaced wrong code, but now I've changed the code.

Comment: Try to alert that data.status, data.msg, just to check whether it works

Comment: @SarathSprakash:Yes, I've tried to put all the data parameters received. The alert shows all the parameters.

Comment: have you added the plugin for colorbox

Comment: @SarathSprakash:Yes I did, otherwise how my previous colorbox which is present in this file should work?

Comment: @PHPGeek , so try it removing those if condition and all, just to check

Comment: @SarathSprakash:I tried by removinf if-else block but still it's not showing the colorbox.

Comment: could you sen the code to cleardoubts123@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

try adding `open: true`, like:

```
$.colorbox({
    inline:true, 
    href: "#emailinfoPopContent",
    width:666,
    open: true
});
```

Comment: :I made the change as per your answer, but still the pop-up is not getting displayed.

Comment: :Have you find any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I am not sure about this

```
var show_html = $('emailinfoPopContent').html();
   $.colorbox({html:show_html});
```

Comment: :I don't want to use jQuery dialog's modal. I want to show the message using jQuery colorbox. Do you have any solution for it?